# How to check if an integer matches given expression of "5+4n"?

Tags: java

What can be an efficient way to determine if a given integer matches the result of an expression `5+4n`. Say, I have a number `54` and I want to check if expression given above can result in this number. One way I can think of is to evaluate `5+4n` up to `54` and check if the result matches the number of interest. But it will be an inefficient way to go when I'll have to check big numbers.

Comment: `return n % 4 == 1;`  Does it have to be necessarily positive?  Is the expression static or could it change?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah, numbers for check are always positive and the expression is static.

Comment: @Neil it should be 0 isnt it

Comment: @HRgiger, nope, 1 is valid.

Comment: @HRgiger It isn't just a multiple of 4, it is a multiple of 4 plus 5, which leaves an remainder of 1.

Comment: @HRgiger You could write it as `(5+4*n) % 4` = `5 % 4` = `1`, if `n >= -1`

Comment: @fabian, nope. Your expression will always return 1. Read my question carefully.

Comment: You are trying to test for a integer `x`, if there is a integer `n` such that `x == (5 + 4 * n)`. What I've written is just the RHS modulo 4. which tells us that it should be `n % 4 == 1` not `n % 4 == 0`.

Comment: if you expand that to `A+Bn`, where A and B are configurable parameters, then to create dynamic validator you can write `return x % B == A % B`

Comment: @Neil I though you ment (x-5)%4 = 1 as Adrian example, clear now:)

Answer (score 1):

If we are assuming that x will always be greater than or equal to 0, `x=5+4n` can be rewritten as `x=1+4(n+1)`. 
This means that when x is divided by 4, there will be a remainder of 1. So you can simply do the below:

```
private boolean doesMatch(x number) {
    return x%4==1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to evaluate the expression A+Bn, with A and B configurable, you should extract A and B first:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\-?\\d+)\\s*\\+([\\-\\+]?\\d+)\\s*n");
Matcher m = p.matcher(expression);
if (m.matches()) {
   int A = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
   int B = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));

   // Evaluate expression
   ...
}
```

and then simply check if `x` is a solution:

```
// Evaluate expression
if ((x-A) % B == 0) {
    // Number is a solution 
} else {
    // Number is not a solution for the expression
}
```